# Фиксированный и центрированный макет

Tags: html, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Есть макет, ширина которого `1638px`.
Фон за `footer`-ом/`header`-ом тянется, т.е. черный фон хедера при изменении масштаба должен быть на всю ширину окна, а контент центрирован, сайт не резиновый. 
Каким образом это реализовать? Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: При изменении ширины области просмотра или всё же при изменении масштаба?

Answer (score 0):

Задавать ширину контента. Например `max-width: 1200px`. А цвет фона задавать его родителю без привязки к ширине, ну или 100% ставить.

```css
section {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 7%;
}

.content {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(33% - 20px);
  height: 65px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Каким образом задать ширину 1638px?

Comment: В свойстве `max-width` можете какую хотите ширину задать